# Running multiple docker containers listening on same port for RabbitMQ messages

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I'm running a RabbitMQ container using the following command:

```
docker run --name sl-rabbitmq-mgmt-dev --publish=15672:15672/tcp --publish=5672:5672/tcp --hostname=rabbitmq --detach rabbitmq:3-management
```

*Port 15672 is for the management console, the main port for communication is 5672*

I have multiple .NET Core docker images that listen/subscribe to port 5672 to listen for incoming messages for a queue, and push messages to a queue.

There can/will be multiple instances ("workers") of a .dll running. Running one instance is fine for local development, but multiple will be running in PROD.

[image]

When I attempt to run my docker image of the .dll (i.e. Process1.dll)

```
docker run --rm --publish=5672:5672/tcp --detach process1:latest
```

it indicates that a container is already bound to that port on 0.0.0.0:/5672

I'm assuming a docker-compose file will be needed to accomplish what I'm setting out for.

How can I accomplish running these multiple containers on the same port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RabbitMQ workflow is that the broker needs to listen on port 5672.  Producers and consumer need to make outbound connections to that port on the broker, but they don’t themselves need to accept inbound connections.

This means that you can remove the `--publish` option from your worker containers.  They will still be able to make *outbound* connections to RabbitMQ, and you won’t have the port conflict.

Comment: A consumer can't be cut-off from the outside world - not sure how you think it would receive a message if no ports are open?

Comment: The consumer calls RabbitMQ, not vice versa.  Once the consumer’s connected it keeps an open channel.  It can in fact be totally cut off.

Comment: (In the same way that you don’t need to allow inbound connections on ports 80/443 to make outbound HTTP connections.)

Comment: you we're right, removing the --publish for this worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to run multiple containers on the same port on the host.
Or you need change your solution. For example change port.

Comment: Pretty sure that's not how a 3rd party message broker works....(I.e. I can't just change the port that each worker listens to, wouldn't make sense).